# Atom Create New File using API in Specific Directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, coffeescript, atom-editor

What am I trying to do is making a copy of file in specific directory before saving.

```
@sss= new CompositeDisposable
@sss.add atom.workspace.observeTextEditors (editor)=>
    @sss.add editor.buffer.onWillSave => # BUG: this is not working till I lunch web browser
        #if atom.config.get("search-the-web.browser.verbose_backup_directory") is not 'null'
        file_prefix = new Date().toLocaleString().replace(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+).*?(\d+):(\d+):(\d+) .*/,"$3$1$2$4$5$6")
        copyPath = atom.config.get("search-the-web.browser.verbose_backup_directory") + editor.buffer.file.path.replace(/(.):/,"\\$1").replace(/(\.(?:.(?!\.))+$)/,"-#{file_prefix}$1")
        console.log(copyPath);
```

File Doc: https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.31.2/File
Directory Doc: https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.31.2/Directory

I can't understand document on atom.io website and I didn't found any relevant answer on internet, can someone help please. I am using coffee-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import {File} from 'atom'
const myFile = new File("d:\\hello.txt");
myFile.write("testing");
```

Here I found solution.